# What is nonpaged pool?

Tags: memory-leak, virtual-memory

I have a Server 2008 R2 that I maintain on a day-to-day basis.
The server is good and operating fine but it keeps sending me event 2019 error logs.
"The server was unable to allocate from the system nonpaged pool because the pool was empty."

Is Nonpaged memory the same as virtual-memory? As well with Paged Memory the same as physical memory?
How to check if a system or driver is using either physical or virtual memory?

I checked on Task Manager -> Performance to see if it has allocated nonpage memory on the system and it does.
I just wonder that this error is trying to say or warn me perhaps.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Nonpaged pool is kernel memory which can't be paged out into the pagefile when Windows runs out of free physical memory. It is used by drivers to allocate memory which they need.

Post some pictures of taskmgr, when you into the issue. If the usage is too large, [use poolmon to find the causing driver of the leak](https://superuser.com/a/674725/174557).